# Given that $\sin A = \frac{4}{5}$, $\cos(A+B) = \frac{5}{13}$ and that $A$ and $B$ are acute, find $\cos B$

Tags: trigonometry

I've used the angle sum identity to end up with $\cos A \cos B -\sin A \sin B = \frac{5}{13} = \frac{3}{5}\cos B -\frac{4}{5} \sin B$, but don't know how to proceed from here. Any tips?

Comment: Using your equation, you have $(\frac{5}{13} - \frac{3}{5}\cos B)^2 = (\frac{4}{5} \sin B)^2$. Express $\sin^2 B = 1 - \cos^2 B$, replace $x = \cos B$  and solve  the quadratic equation for $x$. Pick the result which corresponds to $B$ acute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint $\cos B=\cos((A+B)-A)$ use the compound angle formula

Answer (score 1):

$$A=\arcsin\dfrac45=\arccos\dfrac35$$

$$A+B=\arccos\dfrac5{13}=\arcsin\dfrac{12}{13}$$

$$B=\arccos\dfrac5{13}-\arccos\dfrac35$$